# Exception in cache evict operation spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

Hi there i'm trying to cache the categories which are first queried from the database in Redis for better performance.

When I query for all the categories the cache is created and performance of the same request improves drastically, however when I try to evict the cache when I'm saving a new category I receive this exception:

```
Cannot convert cache key com.xxx.xxx.xxx.categories.Category to String. Please register a suitable Converter via 'RedisCacheConfiguration.configureKeyConverters(...)' or override 'Category.toString()'.
```

Now I tried saving before creating cache, and I still got the same exception.

This is my cache config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MyProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(properties.getCache().getRedisCacheEntryTtl()))
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    }
}
```

and this is my service layer:

```
    @CacheEvict(value = CacheConstants.CACHE_NAME_PREFIX + "categories")
    public Category persist(Category entity) {
        return repo.save(entity);
    }

    @Cacheable(value = CacheConstants.CACHE_NAME_PREFIX + "categories", unless = "#result == null")
    public List<Category> listAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Cacheable, whatever argument you are passing will become your key. Here you are not passing any key, so default SimpleKey.EMPTY will become your key. Now while CacheEvict, your Category class object become your key and therefore your are getting that error. Instead use custom key

Comment: yeah that worked ty for the help